# How to push an item (struct type) from vector1 to vector2 in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

How to push an item (struct type) from vector1 to vector2 in Rust? Can someone help me?

```rust
let mut vec1: Vec<Struct1> = vec![];

    let item1 = Struct1 {
        id: 1,
        name: "AlgoQ".to_string()
    };

    vec1.push(item1);
    let mut vec2: Vec<Struct1> = vec![];

    vec2.push(&vec1[0]);

    vec1.pop();
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/test4.rs:17:15
   |
17 |     vec2.push(&vec1[0]);
   |               ^^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               expected struct `Struct1`, found `&Struct1`
   |               help: consider removing the borrow: `vec1[0]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your item can't be at both place. You have to either

1. remove the item from the source vector:

```rust
vec2.push(vec1.remove(0));
```

Here, as you also want to pop from the first vector, you may directly do

```rust
if let Some(item) = vec1.pop() {
    vec2.push(item);
}
```

But be careful that `pop` removes at the end, not at index `0` so your snippet is a little obscure regarding your exact intent.

2. or clone the item (assuming it can be cloned)

```rust
vec2.push(vec1[0].clone());
```

---

Now, if you really want the item to be, conceptually, at two places, you may store references (ie `&Struct1`) or indexes in your second vec.